# How can I extract all words with a specific colour out of a PDF?

Tags: pdf

Is there any convenient way of extracting/outputting words which have a specific colour out of a PDF document? 
In my case, I have some beamer PDFs and I'd like to extract all words in red.

Comment: Which is your preferred programming environment, which Java library du you use?

Comment: Actually, I was not thinking of a programmatical approach which means I am open for any solution.

Comment: stack overflow predominantly is a site for programming questions. If you are looking for other approaches, you might want to ask on another stack exchange site.